# How to see traceback on xmlrpc server, not client?

Tags: python, multithreading, simplexmlrpcserver, xmlrpclib, xmlrpcclient

I have simple xmlrpc server code:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

port = 9999

def func():
    print 'Hi!'
    print x # error!
    print 'Bye!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", port))
    print "Listening on port %s..." % port
    server.register_function(func)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Sample session.

*Client:*

```
>>> import xmlrpclib
>>> p = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:9999')
>>> p.func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1199, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1489, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Python26\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1253, in request
    return self._parse_response(h.getfile(), sock)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1392, in _parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 838, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: "<type 'exceptions.NameError'>:global name 'x' is not defined">
>>>
```

*Server:*

```
Listening on port 9999...
Hi!
localhost - - [11/Jan/2011 16:17:09] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

The question is if I can get this trace back also on server. I need to know if something went wrong with processing query. I'm not using client written in Python so it is hard for me to get traceback like above.

Comment: Your question is really confusing. You say you're not using a client in python, but your client is python code.

Comment: Yes, but that is just example. As client I'm using some dll which base on xmlrpc-c library. And I really don't want to change code of this dll...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer, SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

port = 9999

def func():
    print 'Hi!'
    print x # error!
    print 'Bye!'

class Handler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
     def _dispatch(self, method, params):
         try: 
             return self.server.funcs[method](*params)
         except:
             import traceback
             traceback.print_exc()
             raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", port), Handler)
    server.register_function(func)
    print "Listening on port %s..." % port
    server.serve_forever()
```

Traceback server side:

```
Listening on port 9999...
Hi!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml.py", line 13, in _dispatch
    value = self.server.funcs[method](*params)
  File "xml.py", line 7, in func
    print x # error!
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
localhost - - [11/Jan/2011 17:13:16] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.0" 200
```

Comment: This will have saved me days of head banging.  Thanks.

Comment: should explicitly use requestHandler keyword, `SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", port), requestHandler=Handler)`